# Composition of two linear transformations (matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

my name is Shaun and I am 14 years old.

I am trying to learn linear transformations via matrices and I wanted to ask about matrix composition; why does the method of matrix multiplication work? I have searched up on [Khan Academy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kT4Mp9EdVqs) and [3blue1brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkY2DOUCWMU&t=9s&pp=ygURbWF0cml4IGNvbXBvc3Rpb24%3D) on it.

For instance, if I have a vector *v* and I want to first rotate then shear it, it can be expressed mathematically in the following way: **AB***v*, where B (the rotate matrix) is defined as $$
\begin{matrix}
 [i_R ,& j_R ] \\
\end{matrix}
$$

and A (the shear matrix) is defined as $$
\begin{matrix}
[i_S ,& j_S] \\
\end{matrix}
$$

where R and S respectively mean "Rotated" and "Shear"

According to Khan Academy, Sal explains that one multiplies each row in one matrix with every single column in the other matrix;
and according to 3b1b, he explains that one takes i_R and multiplies it with the *whole* shear matrix and then same thing for j_R. After that, just add the two up.

However, I do not understand why these two methods, the standard method and the other method, work. The calculations seems counterintuitive for me.

I understand the intuition behind matrix composition, that it is supposed to transform the vector *v*. I just do not understand the way we compute matrix multiplication.

Thanks for help and sorry if it considered an elementary question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a different way to compute the same:

Kahn academy does this: $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}ae+bg&af+bh\\ce+dg&cf+dh\end{pmatrix},$$
which calculates the product "directly".

3blue1brown does this:
$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\cdot\left[\begin{pmatrix}e&0\\g&0 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&f\\0&h \end{pmatrix}\right]\\ 
&= \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}e&0\\g&0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0&f\\0&h \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}ae+bg&0\\ce+dg&0\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0&af+bh\\0&cf+dh\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}ae+bg&af+bh\\ce+dg&cf+dh\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}$$

It is actually a way of geometrically motivating why the matrix multiplication is the way it is. Namely, you want it to correspond with composing the transformations described by the matrices.

Note that when multiplying a matrix and a vector, you can see the vector as a matrix with one column and the multiplication will work in the exact same way as Kahn academy described. This should explain why those 2 ways of computing give the same result. (If you are not convinced. Multiply 2 matrices both ways and note that you are actually doing the same thing)

Comment: Does (0,0) mean that there is no value to it? I am little confused however this is a nice way of explaining it,

Comment: Like, when you put (e, g) and then (0,0), does that equal to (e,g)?

Comment: And, in the first line of showing how 3b1b does it, can you multiply a matrix with the sum of two vectors like that? I thought that only applies to scalar algebra, like 3(x+y) = 3x + 3y

Comment: sorry for lots of questions, just trying to learn.

Comment: Distributivity works for matrices as well, this is actually a proof for that since you can just calculate what you get and see, oh I get the same thing. Regarding your other question. $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}e&0\\f&0\end{pmatrix}$ is the same as $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}e\\f\end{pmatrix}$ where you add a column of zeros at the end. You can see it because of how you multiply a matrix with a vector and by seeing that the elements of the first column of the result matrix only depend on the first column of the second matrix.

Comment: Thank you Vincent!

Comment: It is a bit tricky to explain but it comes down to the fact that if you multiply a matrix with a vector, to get the $i$-th element of the result vector, you (just like with matrices) multiply the $i$-th row with the vector. If you now look at matrices you can see that what you are doing is exactly the same as if you would treat that column as a vector and calculate those elements ($i$-th row times that column). (With "multiplying rows and columns" I mean multiplying the $i$-th elements and summing those products)